# Creating a unique name for .jtl file in command line

Tags: jmeter

I am running some jmeter tests through command line, and in that command I have the statement:

```
-l testresults.jtl
```

which of course outputs the jmeter results into a file that is called "testresults". My question is:

> Is there a way in command line to give a unique name to the test
>   results file?

I would like to append the name of the test, along with a time stamp in order to keep it unique.

Comment: are you executing the command manually or do you do it via a script?

Comment: executing via command line, manually

Comment: Well then you will be typing in the command, so you can give any name of your choice to the JTL file. If you want to make it unique use incremental numbers in combination to the textual name you have thought for the results. For example, results1.jtl, results2.jtl

Comment: Right, i'm aware of this. Essentially I am trying to reduce the amount of changing in the command, by injecting some form of variable. So that I don't need to edit the output file every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a Windows based system,

Open notepad and write the below piece of code in it.

```
C:\ set SAVESTAMP=%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-%
C:\ set SAVESTAMP=%SAVESTAMP: =%
C:\ set SAVESTAMP=%SAVESTAMP:,=.%.jtl

jmeter -n -t "Your .jmx file path" -l %SAVESTAMP%
```

Now save this as a batch cript - `filename.bat`

Go to the location where you saved your file and run it by double-click or select and enter.

This should do the trick for you.

On Linux based system you might want to run it with a similar shell script.

Answer (score 3):

**JMeter-only solution**:

1. Add a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice to the test plan and configure to store it whatever you want in a file.
2. Use [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function as a part of file name to make current timestamp a part of it

**Non-JMeter solution**

Your question itself is not very related to JMeter, you can pass whatever you want via `-l` parameter and JMeter tries to store test results in that location, so few ideas on getting timestamps:

- [Windows Powershell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShellv): `Get-Date -UFormat "%s"`
- Linux/Unix/MacOSX ([bash shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))): `date +%s`
- [Apache Ant](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/): [tstamp task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html)
- Apache Maven: [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) automatically appends timestamp to results files

Demo:

[image: JMeter Command Line Timestamp Demp]

For more information on different ways of launching JMeter tests without using GUI check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article

Comment: So I am on a windows 7 machine running these scripts, listeners don't work because I am using distributed machines. How is it possible to use windows powershell to input the date/time into the file name in command line?

Comment: The answer is above: `Get-Date -UFormat "%s"`, if you need different format refer to [Get-Date documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date)

Comment: Placing the above answer into cmd gets an error

Answer (score 0):

Use the below, predefined, property of JMETER to parameterize the file name.

```
${START.HMS}testresults.jtl
```

It gives a unique result file name.